# After:content text rendering strangely in IE 11

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I am using CSS after (very cool thing) to generate a "popup" that works far, far better than title does, usually.

I have a problem with IE (surprise, surprise), where a popup, mediated using CSS's after thingy, is showing up perfectly in Chrome, but renders quite badly in IE 11.

[image]

Versus in Chrome:

[image]

The css is like this:

```
*[data-holiday]::after{
    background:#fefdcd;
    border:1px solid #c0c0c0;
    box-shadow:2px 4px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    color:black;
    content:attr(data-holiday);
    display:block;
    font-size:0.8rem;
    left: 50px;
    line-height:1.0rem;
    position:absolute;
/*  opacity:0;  */
    top:10px;
    padding:2px 2px;
    pointer-events:none;
    width:160px;
    z-index:100;
}
```

with markup providing the content for "data-holiday"

```
<div style="position:absolute;top:0px;right:160px;font-size:0.8rem;" data-holiday="[content for display here]">
```

NOTE: opacity was temporarily commented out, to get the screen captures. OnHover is used in css to modify this ordinarily.

Usually I can sort out how to hand-hold IE, but this time I have no clues. Any one see what I'm missing?

I tried putting br's in the text, made no difference. FYI, the content is just plain text, no formatting, no HTML.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know what the problem is (must do some more research to find out the cause), but you can solve it by changing the line height to `line-height:1.25;` instead of `1.0rem`.

Comment: A good suggestion; I didn't think to try that. Unfortunately, it seems to make no difference. Still rendering all on a single, half-height line in IE

Comment: Oops, that DID "fix" it. Typos, on top of everything else. That gives a normal line spacing for IE, but gives the expected line-spacing in Chrome, is not acceptable. I'll try to sort it out to do that only under IE. I'd still like to know why it's happening, though.

Comment: I got it. Just remove the line height altogether. Works as expected every where now. What was I thinking to put in there in the first place?

Comment: Setting a specific line height won't normally do any harm. And it allows you to find out the heights of things... (a block with a line height of 1rem is 1rem high, so there). There's a bug report about this, filed in 2013: https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/776744 And then it was marked solved in 2015. Oh well.